# Initializing a pointer from a base address

Tags: c++

I am working on a trainer for a little game and I found the base addresses for HP ('THREADSTACK0'-00000414). How would you initialize a pointer with this address?

Comment: Depending on your environment, something like `int* pointer = (int*)('THREADSTACK0'-00000414);`? Note that `'THREADSTACK0'` is a multi-character character constant having implementation-defined value and `00000414` is an octal literal having value `268` in decimal.

Comment: alright ill give it a whirl thanks

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that this data is coming from a debugger, where `THREADSTACK0` is some identifier and `00000414` is an address in hex format (debuggers don't usually use octal).  So `void* pointer = (void*)0x00000414;` or better: `void* pointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x00000414);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how game/Process address works.
Process have their own address space.

**Address = process base address + offset.**

in your case base address is address of your process/game 
it looks like RAW -> **0x0040000** and in Cheat engine it looks like this "GAME_NAME.exe".

and then there is offset lets say **0007B14**

so to get to address you have to add **base address** + **offset**.

hp_address = **0x0040000** + **0007B14**

i made a game trainer library for C/C++ that will help to find game process, get game base address and read write address/pointers easily into any game.

[GTLibc Trainer Library](https://github.com/haseeb-heaven/GTLibc)